# usage of import with plain header files

Tags: c++, import, header-files, c++20

Is it good practice to get rid of `#include` and only use the `import` keyword instead even for headers (like `<span>` or `"Foo.h"`)? Are there any benefits to this? Any possible downsides? Does it add to the length of build time?

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/import) has an example in which it says this:

> import <set>; // imports a synthesized header unit formed from header

What exactly does *synthesized* mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any benefits to this?

Importing synthesised header units instead of including the header may satisfy a style guide that wants to use one type of directive for both modules and headers.

> Any possible downsides?

It won't work in pre-C++20 code, nor compilers that haven't yet implemented importing header files. This won't matter if you also use modules, since those won't work pre-C++20 either.

Comment: Nice. Another question is does the preprocessor still play a role when using `import`?

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, the header will be pre-processed.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this feature is to compile the header (including, for instance, preprocessing and parsing but not all template instantiations) **once** rather than once per translation unit that uses it.  It works only if your header files are “well behaved” in the sense that they include everything they need (which is not *universally* accepted as a good idea) and don’t **depend** on inclusion order or external macro definitions.  It tends to make the first importing translation unit slightly slower to build but makes building any **subsequent** importers significantly faster.

“Synthesized” refers to the fact that the compiler acts as if the header file were a **source** file that it had been directed to compile separately rather than merely as part of a translation unit.